# How to access DBFS files located in an S3 bucket from a distributed environment?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks

I have files stored in S3 buckets on `prod` and `test` environments. My code will be executed in a distributed system on both environments. And I want to access the files from DBFS since DBFS is backed by S3 and its bucket mount is a pointer to an S3 location.

How do I access the files from the code not knowing where it's executed (prod or test) ? 
Currently I've managed to access a file on the test env like this:

```
private static final File DATA_FILE = new File("/dbfs/mnt/test-env-bucket/data/test-data.json");
```

But I need to provide a relative path to a DBFS file like `/data/test-data.json` and somehow detect whether we are on `prod` or `test` environment and chose the bucket accordingly. How can I achieve this if the `test-data.json` file exists in both test-env-bucket and prod-env-bucket on S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have two databricks instance?

Try to mount differente points like this

prod:

```
dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, AWS_PRODUCTION_BUCKET_NAME), "/mnt/data")
```

dev:

```
dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, ENCODED_SECRET_KEY, AWS_DEVELOP_BUCKET_NAME), "/mnt/data")
```

and use only:

```
private static final File DATA_FILE = new File("/dbfs/mnt/data/test-data.json");
```